# Can I change gcc default options without using command-line?

Tags: gcc, configure, gentoo

I am plagued by the [Gentoo bug #580414](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580414).
In short, the default options mislead **configure** into not detecting standard include files because some headers contain this code:

```
#if defined _FORTIFY_SOURCE && _FORTIFY_SOURCE > 0
# if !defined __OPTIMIZE__ || __OPTIMIZE__ <= 0
#  warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)
```

, and **__OPTIMIZE__** is off by default and  **_FORTIFY_SOURCE** is on by default, and the generated warning is perceived as an error, indicating that "stdint.h", "stdlib.h" and many others are absent. Compilation eventually fails and I cannot install programs or even upgrade the gcc itself.

Can I simply put something in environment vars or in the /etc directory to turn on -O or turn off _FORTIFY_SOURCE for **every** invocation of gcc without editing gentoo build scripts?

### Tried in /etc/portage/make.conf

```
EPATCH_USER_EXCLUDE='*10_all_default-fortify-source*'
CFLAGS="-O2 -O -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0"
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-O2 -O -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE"
```

without any improvement.

Comment: use `/etc/portage/make.conf` to set desired `CFLAGS` and/or `CXXFLAGS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such environment variable. `CFLAGS` in `make.conf` won't work because the build systems usually do something like this:

```
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(MY_HARDCODED_CFLAGS)
```

thus overwriting your flags.

But to mangle any argument passed to gcc, you can use the following workaround.

1. create a directory, eg. under `/usr/local/bin/`
2. create a script which will mangle its arguments as you wish and then passes them to `gcc` or `"/usr/bin/" + basename(argv[0])` (beware of infinite recursion)
3. make this script executable
4. create symlinks to the script in that directory with names like `gcc`, `cc`, `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc`
5. put a bunch of lines like this into `/etc/portage/bashrc`:

   ```
   the_dir="/usr/local/bin/THE_DIR"
   if [[ "${PATH}" != *"${the_dir}"* ]] ; then
       export PATH="${the_dir}:${PATH}"
   fi
   ```

Also to save yourself from possible problems in the future, do not forget to put a note about this change somewhere. (As should be done with any workaround anyway.)

Comment: At long last, after a year I get to recompile gcc (4.6->6.2)! Your suggestion was an eye opener, but configure did not pick up the gentle substitution you suggested. I had to rename /usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++ itself (and friends).

Answer (score 0):

Just documenting the commands I actually used to resolve the issue.

```
mv /usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc /usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc.OLD
cat >/usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
/usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc.OLD -O "$@"
```

<kbd>ctrl+D</kbd>

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
cp /usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.6.3/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc /usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.6.3/i686-pc-linux-gnuu-gcc
mv /usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++ /usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnuu-g++
cat >/usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++
/usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnuu-g++ -O "$@"
```

<kbd>ctrl+D</kbd>

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++
cp /usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.6.3/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++ /usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.6.3/i686-pc-linux-gnuu-g++
cp /etc/env.d/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu-4.6.3.O /etc/env.d/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnuu-4.6.3
```

The credit all goes to [rindeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566213/rindeal). Recap:

1. identify the binaries that get invoked as compilers
2. rename them
3. in their place, create shell scripts that prepend "-O"
4. create a gcc profile to appease gcc-config
5. emerge all the unwieldy packages!